# Open a shapefile in folders without using "add folder connections"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, catalog-pane

[image: [![My ArcGIS catalog pane][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxXws.jpg]

I am new to ArcGIS Pro and having trouble opening a shapefile in "folders" on the catalog pane. I can right click on "folders" and "add folder connections" but this puts the shapefile in a subfolder in "folders." You can see on the attached image that parcels shapefile is inside a folder called "zip folder." How do I get the shapefile out of the extra "zip folder" folder so it is just in the  folder? ( In my attached image the  folder is "arcGIS_basic" )

Comment: Zipfiles might present as folders, but they aren't, they're files. You need to extract the data to obtain access.

Comment: Just drag and drop fname.shp using windows explorer to display it. This will help to avoid data duplication.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to right-click on your shapefile to choose Copy.

Then right-click on your arcGIS_basic folder and choose Paste.

Once you have the copy done, right-click on the original shapefile again to choose Delete.

Alternatively, use Windows Explorer to Cut/Paste the shapefile (make sure you get all the files that are part of it) from the zipfolder folder to the arcGIS_basic folder.

Comment: Note that "shapefile" in this case is *all* the files with the same prefix as the file ending in `.shp` (e.g., foo.shp, foo.shx, foo.dbf, foo.prj, foo.shp.xml, ...)